# WYSIWYG editor for MeteorJS with image upload options

Tags: meteor, reactjs, wysiwyg

I've tried most of the packages from https://atmospherejs.com/ but nothing seems to work with Meteor 1.3. Are there any editors for Meteor somewhat like Wordpress's TinyMCE?

I'm using React with Meteor and ES6. Trying to make a blog like CMS for myself.

(I've just started Meteor so I'm a noob in this platform)

Comment: Take a look at https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/ :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply @Gemmi ! It's simple and feature filled, but it does not support images yet? (Like TinyMCE) - been through all the examples in its git repo

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE got their own React module which worked for me - [TinyMCE React](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/react/)

If anyone gets an error like: tinymce is not defined...

You can do-

- Add a script in your footer :

  ```
  src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"
  ```
- Copy the whole script into your code, so that Meteor could merge it
  for you
- Add the script on a component level using dangerouslySetInnerHTML
  function inside componentDidMount or anywhere you want